# Execution time difference between psycopg2 and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Out of sheer curiosity, does anyone know why I am experiencing a difference in execution time for the exact same setup in SQLAlchemy compared to psycopg2 while connecting to a PostgreSQL DB?

From what I can tell SQLAlchemy is taking longer to initialize but I do not know why. Does this matter?(I have been recommended SQLAlchemy of psycopg2 but its slower). It takes about 3 times longer.

```
start = time.time() 
    ...: engine_str = 'enginestr' 
    ...: try: 
    ...:         engine = create_engine(engine_str) 
    ...:         conn = engine.connect() 
    ...: except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: 
    ...:         raise ConnectionError("Check VPN connection") 
    ...: ms = Table('measurement_stat',metadata,autoload = True, 
    ...:                autoload_with = engine) 
    ...: times = cf.display_modemap_start_times(ms, 10, conn) 
    ...: stop = time.time() 
    ...: print(stop-start)                                                                                                                                                                                  
3.546764850616455

In [25]: start = time.time() 
    ...: params = {'database': 'dbname', 
    ...:               'user': 'uname', 
    ...:               'password': 'passwd', 
    ...:               'host': 'hostname', 
    ...:               'port': 30000 
    ...:              } 
    ...: try: 
    ...:      conn = pg2.connect(**params, connect_timeout = 5) #connects to postgres 
    ...:      cur = conn.cursor() 
    ...: except pg2.OperationalError: 
    ...:     print("CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE.CHECK VPN CONNECTION") 
    ...: modemap_start_sql = F"SELECT timestamp FROM measurement_stat WHERE sensor_name = 'modemap_measurement_status' AND value_cal = 'start_measurement' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT {10};" 
    ...: cur.execute(modemap_start_sql) 
    ...: start_times = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall()) 
    ...: start_times.columns = ['modemap_start_time']     
    ...: stop = time.time() 
    ...: print(stop-start)                                                                                                                                                                                  
1.190742015838623
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These packages serve different purpose. `psycopg` implements the protocol of talking to the DB, while `sqlalchemy` adds an object abstraction on top of the obtained raw values.

In fact, `sqlalchemy` internally uses `psycopg` to talk to the database, so there is no way it can be faster or even the same because of object creation overhead.

The reason to use `sqlalchemy` is maintainability of the code, not the speed. If you have a non-trivial system, every change in the DB will propagate in massive code changes and collateral bugs. With `sqlalchemy`, you only have to change one object definition to match the new DB structure.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I was aware of the object creation overhead. However, I didn't expect the difference to be that big. Seems like MetaData is the part that takes the longest and I am not particularly sure why that step is even necessary unlike psycopg2.